# Connecting 2 drop down lists in Peoplesoft

Tags: peoplesoft

on a specific page that I am developping; I have 2 drop down lists that I have to connect, the first one shows XLAT operands ( equals, different, greater than...) and the second shows values (0,1,2,3,4). The problem is how  can I translate the operands mathematically, so that when I choose 'greater than 2' for example the system gets it (>2)? It should be done with peoplecode? [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmwDK.png) 
 Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code, without that you can't aspect an answer, since nobody can imagine how it works

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do an Evaluate or If/Else over the XLAT from the operands.
What do you want to achieve? Post your code so I can suggest if you go to a SQL statement or PeopleCode.

Comment: Thank You Walucas, I didn't post the code because I'm doing this through a query where i have to return a field having these special characteristics. I solved it through SQL statment via the query manager's criteria.